# Does Integer can return drawable?

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist, return, return-value

I'm making an app and I make an Arraylist to store multiple drawables, but for some reason when I try

```
ArrayList<ImageView> img = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
```

and I try to store drawables directly from drawable directory

```
img.add(R.drawable.img1);
```

It's asking me to change the data type to integer, I don't know how to test this code if it will return the Image or not, so can someone verify what does this code do when I try to get a single value from the ArrayList?

Comment: Is img1 an ImageView? Otherwise I don't see a reason why it would ask for an index here (which is required in an overloaded version the add method)

Comment: *img1* is a drawable that I imported

Comment: If you have a List of Apples, you can only put something in that is related to an Apple, not Bananas. In other words, if you want to store Drawables, you need an ArrayList<Drawable>, because it does not extend ImageView.

Comment: View does implement, however, Drawable.Callback, but that doesn't mean it is compatible. You cannot add Map.Entry<K,V> to List<Map<K,V>> either.

Comment: Please take some time to carefully review / improve your question? Like ... the title?

Answer (score 0):

**ImageView** is UI element that is used to display drawables, it is not the drawable itself.

R.drawables are stored ints indeed and they represent references to those actual drawables you have stored. So if you want to have list of drawables you need to change type of list to int.

And to change which drawable is displayed you can call

```
.setBackgroundResource(img.get(i)) // where i is index of desired drawable
```

on UI element in your case ImageView

Answer (score 0):

R.drawable.* returns Int. So you must have to create an ArrayList of integers.

```
ArrayList<ImageView> img = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    img.add(R.drawable.img1);
    imageView.setImageResource(img.get(1));
```

It will work fine.